# Неверная высота страницы HTML

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Доброго времени суток. Верстал шаблон и получилось так, что неверно определяется высота страницы.

Поясняю: если добавить div с абсолютным позиционированием:

```
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px">
```

то он будет висеть где-то на границе красной области, но никак не у границы окна. Проблема не в браузере, проверял во всех последних версиях. Причем, в IE все, что ниже красной области тупо обрезатся. Код HTML и CSS проходят проверку на валидность. В чем может быть проблема?

Скриншот проблемы.

[image]

Comment: Проблему решил. Во всем было виновато абсолютное позиционирование шапки

Comment: Код в студию!

Comment: проблема решена уже... не понимаю, почему модераторы не закрыли тему

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у блока имеется свойства

```
position: absolute
```

или

```
float: left или right
```

То что бы блок не выходил за рамки родительского блока желательно после блока с перечисленными свойствами ставить

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```